# Working with MP3 sound in Processing for Android ( need to stop )

Tags: android, audio, mp3, processing

I am developing an app for Android devices using Processing 2.0, now I have playMP3(); function but need to stop the sound using stopMP3();. I tried everything but what is the best way to load an mp3 and play/stop using processing?, snd.stop(); within the stopMP3 function does not work...

```
import android.media.*;
import android.content.res.*;
```

...

```
MediaPlayer snd;
```

...

```
    void setup()
{
MediaPlayer snd = new MediaPlayer();
}
```

...

```
void playMP3()
    { 
try {
    AssetManager assets = this.getAssets();
    AssetFileDescriptor fd = assets.openFd("loop1.mp3");
    snd.setDataSource(fd.getFileDescriptor(), fd.getStartOffset(), fd.getLength());
    snd.prepare();
    snd.start();
  snd.setLooping(true);
  }
  catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  catch (IllegalStateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

}

```
void stopMP3(){
????
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling stop()?  Have you tried it with a button to make sure that the mp3 has at least started before you execute stop?

Comment: you can create OnCompletionListener and stop when music finish or create a button to call snd.stop() when user click

Comment: @eskimoapps.com I have a button before the playMP3() function, which starts the sound loop. But don't know how to stop it inside the stop function, maybe there is a command to remove sound or variable from memory on the phone, don't know. Thank you in advance

Comment: @Leon_SFS I already have a button calling the playMP3() function and an if statement which also calls the stopMP3() function but don't know what code could be within that last function. Thanks for your help

Comment: @DavidVera i write the stop function! snd.stop();snd.release();snd.reset();write these code in your stopmp3 function, sns is your MediaPlayer variable name---is that what you want?

Comment: @Leon_SFS It worked partially... snd.reset(); gives an error, removing it works (sound stops), but after snd.stop();snd.release(); I can't use the playMP3(); function again, why? thank you!

Comment: because first you set dataSource for player and when stop you want set again dataSource,it's getting error,you must initial again snd(MediaPlayer Varibale) or reset its,if reset gives error,so try initial again\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a simple sample for media player

```
private MediaPlayer   m_Player;

//Start Play Function
private void startPlaying() {
    m_Player = new MediaPlayer();
    m_Player.setOnCompletionListener(onComplete);
    try {
        if(m_Player.isPlaying())
            stopPlaying();

        m_Player.setDataSource(m_FileName);
        m_Player.prepare();
        m_Player.start();

    } catch (IOException e) {

    }
}

//Stop Play Function
private void stopPlaying() {
    m_Player.stop();
    m_Player.reset();
    m_Player = null;
}

//and this is onComplete Listener
MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener onComplete = new OnCompletionListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp)
    {
        stopPlaying();
    }
};
```

i hope it's helping you